# Google webmaster tools HTML suggestions - duplicate meta descriptions

Tags: php, seo

When i look in my webmaster tools account i have hundreads of dupliacte meta descriptions. When i look at each one the duplicate urls's are like so:

```
/in​dex​.ph​p?r​out​e=p​rod​uct​/pr​odu​ct&​pro​duc​t_i​d=1​58?​48e​fc5​20 
/in​dex​.ph​p?r​out​e=p​rod​uct​/pr​odu​ct&​pro​duc​t_i​d=1​58?​abc56c80
```

Where are these numbers coming from after my product id????

Thanks

Pjn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resolve this, add code to 301 redirect Urls with extraneous parameters to the canonical Url.  For example, redirect /in​dex​.ph​p?r​out​e=p​rod​uct​/pr​odu​ct&​pro​duc​t_i​d=1​58?​48e​fc5​20 to 
/in​dex​.ph​p?r​out​e=p​rod​uct​/pr​odu​ct&​pro​duc​t_i​d=1​58

Assuming these extraneous parameters are indeed not being used.

Stackoverflow does this, see how this Url redirects:
[Google webmaster tools HTML suggestions - duplicate meta descriptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6585933/this-will-redirect)

Answer (score 1):

That means that the `<meta name="description" content="...">` is the same for several pages.

Since you're not sure how the additional parameters are added to your URL, you could use the `link` tag to specify the `canonical` URL. This needs to be added to the `head` of each page.

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://www.example.com/product.php?item=swedish-fish" />
```

For more information, have a look at http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2009/02/specify-your-canonical.html.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a referral system or something in place? Those are querystrings, and without the name part of the usual name=value pair, they tend to look like those for referrals.

Is this in a system you build yourself, or are you using something?

Without more information about your setup, it will be tough to diagnose.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say where Google "learned" the names. You can some things in Webmaster Tools to avoid the reports.

One is the canonical like somebody mentioned. The other is in Webmaster Tools in Site Configuration/Settings. Click the Parameter Handling tab and enter your exceptions